# How to find part numbers that have a certain string in their description

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset with two columns, "PartNumber" and "OperationDescription".

I am trying to find all of the part numbers that have the word "Debulk in their description. Then, I want to find the number of times that occurs for each part number. I am using R, any advice?

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
   filter(str_detect(OperationDescription, 'Debulk')) %>%
   group_by(PartNumber) %>%
   count()
```